# variable filetypes in tk_getOpenFile

Tags: tcl, file-type

The tcl routine to get a file name (for open) is tk_getOpenFile. The specification of the allowable suffixes is like this:

```
set fileTypes { 
           {"Image Files" { .tiff .TIFF .cr2 .CR2 .nef .NEF }}
           {"All files" {*} }
           }
```

Replacing the .tiff ... .NEF list with a variable name results in the un-expanded variable name. I'd rather not hard-code this suffix list in the procedure. Is there any way to use a variable to specify the list of suffixes (suffixi) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
set imgFT { .tiff .TIFF .cr2 .CR2 .nef .NEF }
set fileTypes {}
lappend fileTypes [list "Image Files" $imgFT]
lappend fileTypes {"All files" {*}}
```

To use a variable in the list, you can't use braces to delimit the list. If you instead use `list` and build up the result list item by item it will work.

Documentation:
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: Sorry, my English is worse than ever this evening. Hopefully it's understandable anyway.

Comment: My mastery of building lists is deficient because my attempts were rejected by the 'file open' routine. But it is useful to know that one should not use braces to build lists - I assume you mean, when they contain a variable that should be expanded. Thanks for answering- Peter

Answer (score 1):

It's just a list of elements. Each of the elements is itself a list where the first element is the type name and the second is the list of extensions. (There's a third element possible in there, but you probably don't support classic MacOS so you can ignore it.) As such, you can build the lists using Tcl commands; the `list` command is useful here, as is `lappend`.

```
set tiffTypes {.tif .tiff}
lappend tiffTypes .NEF ;    # etc.
set ftlist [list [list "TIFF files" $tiffTypes] {"All files" *}]

tk_getOpenFile -filetypes $ftlist
```

It's just ordinary code. You've just been looking at a list literal that happened to use newlines for some of its whitespace for readability reasons.

Comment: That works a treat. I'm interested that you can do 'lappend tiffTypes .NEF'.  I have always done 'set tiffTypes [lappend tiffTypes .NEF] which is more typing and less clear. Thanks for the help. Peter

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [subst](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/subst.htm) command to substitute a variable with its value inside of curved brackets.

```
set imgFT { .tiff .TIFF .cr2 .CR2 .nef .NEF }
set fileTypes [subst {
         {"Image Files" {$imgFT}}
         {"All files" {*} }
    }]
```

Comment: Ahah! 'subst' was the command that I was looking for, that unpacks a list. The subst manual page has a very nice example: '% set a 44
44
% set b {xyz {$a}}
xyz {$a}
% set b [subst {xyz {$a}}]
xyz {44}'                            Thanks very much - Peter